# OAuth.jsx:17 POST http://localhost:5173/api/auth/google 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: reactjs, oauth

Getting a 500 error for login request(in console) :
***POST http://localhost:5173/api/auth/google 500 (Internal Server Error) .            OAuth.jsx:17
handleGoogleClick@OAuth.jsx:17***

Writing a login page. Not sure where this error is coming from. This is my OAuth.js
If you got anything missing in my code, please help me out.

```
import { GoogleAuthProvider, getAuth, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";
import { app } from "../firebase";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { signInSuccess } from "../redux/user/userSlice";

export default function OAuth() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleGoogleClick = async () => {
    try {
      const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
      const auth = getAuth(app);

      const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);

      const res = await fetch('/api/auth/google', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: result.user.displayName,
          email: result.user.email,
          photo: result.user.photoURL,
        }),
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      dispatch(signInSuccess(data));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("could not sign in with google", error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <button
      onClick={handleGoogleClick}
      type="button"
      className="bg-red-700 text-white p-3 rounded-lg uppercase hover:opacity-95"
    >
      Continue with google
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Title is not obvious

Comment: A server 500 error is an error returned from the server. You should probably start your query there to see what exactly the issue/error was that caused the backend API/server to return a 500 error.